# Wrong output format while running knitr script in TeXworks

Tags: texworks, knitr

I wanted to use `knitr` with my TeXworks install and am noticing a weird issue. I followed the tutorial as described by Yihui [here](https://yihui.org/knitr/demo/editors/#texworks) which worked fine. Now suppose my filename is `untitled-12.tex` and it contains:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a document.

<<>>=
2+2
@

\end{document}
```

Parsing it should (ideally) produce another `.tex` file with the calculated outputs (in the same directory as the above one) and then it was supposed to parse that automatically to give me the final pdf version.

In my case however, I am shown the error:

```
processing file: untitled-12.tex
1/3                  
2/3 [unnamed-chunk-1]
3/3                  
output file: untitled-12.txt

Error in tinytex::latexmk(basename(out), engine = compiler, ...) : 
  The input file 'untitled-12.txt' does not have the .tex extension
Calls: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

This is where I am confused as to why the `output file` is in `.txt` format. I will be glad if someone helped me in this. Also, just for information, this same script ran just fine in LyX, providing the expected output.

I can see a file with the same name in that directory (`untitled-12.txt`) and it contains the following:

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage[]{graphicx}\usepackage[]{xcolor}
% maxwidth is the original width if it is less than linewidth
% otherwise use linewidth (to make sure the graphics do not exceed the margin)
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{ %
  \ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
    \linewidth
  \else
    \Gin@nat@width
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\definecolor{fgcolor}{rgb}{0.345, 0.345, 0.345}
\newcommand{\hlnum}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.686,0.059,0.569}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlstr}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.192,0.494,0.8}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlcom}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.678,0.584,0.686}{\textit{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\hlopt}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlstd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.345,0.345,0.345}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwa}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.161,0.373,0.58}{\textbf{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwb}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.69,0.353,0.396}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwc}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.333,0.667,0.333}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.737,0.353,0.396}{\textbf{#1}}}%
\let\hlipl\hlkwb

\usepackage{framed}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{kframe}{%
 \def\at@end@of@kframe{}%
 \ifinner\ifhmode%
  \def\at@end@of@kframe{\end{minipage}}%
  \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}%
 \fi\fi%
 \def\FrameCommand##1{\hskip\@totalleftmargin \hskip-\fboxsep
 \colorbox{shadecolor}{##1}\hskip-\fboxsep
     % There is no \\@totalrightmargin, so:
     \hskip-\linewidth \hskip-\@totalleftmargin \hskip\columnwidth}%
 \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width
   \@totalleftmargin\z@ \linewidth\hsize
   \@setminipage}}%
 {\par\unskip\endMakeFramed%
 \at@end@of@kframe}
\makeatother

\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.97, .97, .97}
\definecolor{messagecolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{warningcolor}{rgb}{1, 0, 1}
\definecolor{errorcolor}{rgb}{1, 0, 0}
\newenvironment{knitrout}{}{} % an empty environment to be redefined in TeX

\usepackage{alltt}
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\begin{document}
This is a document.

\begin{knitrout}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color{fgcolor}\begin{kframe}
\begin{alltt}
\hlnum{2}\hlopt{+}\hlnum{2}
\end{alltt}
\begin{verbatim}
## [1] 4
\end{verbatim}
\end{kframe}
\end{knitrout}

\end{document}
```

P.S.: I am a LyX user trying to move to a more LaTeX-writing-based experience. As to why I used TeXworks, well I found TeXworks installed along with my MikTeX copy.

Comment: No matter if you are doing something wrong (`.tex` for the Sweawe source?!?)  or Yhui instructions have some bug (not tested),  I would suggest to compile that file with the .Rnw extension in Rstudio, or VS code after install the plugins (and the same extension) or online in Overleaf (with the `.Rtex` textension).

Comment: @Fran Overleaf parses this file flawlessly...

Comment: The problem with Overleaf could be that you depend of a external R with finite packages, but some day you will need some uncommon R package. I always use a local R where I can install anything, but I am not sure if you can do that same in your Overleaf account.

Comment: @Fran I use `knitr` for writing articles inside LyX, which in itself is a latex document processor. So that might indicate that the install works correctly. However, it may be the case that either I did something wrong, or there's some bug in `knitr` which is causing this...

Comment: Yes I got it, I know LyX and knitr well. I'm just suggest that if you want to mess with Sweave/knitr files directly, instead of getting headaches configuring tetxworks, just try Rstudio, which detect your  R and LateX automatically, and handles these files out of the box, and  more.